# Series of exponential integrals

Tags: sequences-and-series, special-functions

Is there a simple expression or approximation for the following series of exponential integrals:

$\sum_{k=1}^\infty E_1(k \nu)$

I believe this can be approximated by $\int_\nu^\infty E_1(x)/\nu \, dx$ for small enough $k$, but I'm interested in a closed form, or at least an estimate for the error from the approximation above.

Comment: It is $\int_0^\infty \lfloor x\rfloor \frac{e^{-x \nu}}{x}dx$. Expanding $\lfloor x\rfloor - x$ in a Fourier series you'll obtain a closed form in term of the Hurwitz zeta function.

Comment: Make this an answer.  It won't cut you off if you hit return.